# Selecting option value of selected element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to select the option value of the selected element in an html dropdown.

**HTML**

```
<select class="select1">
    <option value ="0">" + state.greens[0].name + "</option>
    <option value ="1">" + state.greens[1].name + "</option>
    <option value ="2">" + state.greens[2].name + "</option>
</select>
```

The option values represent an index position in an array that I can load to generate additional data about objects within them.

I'm trying to use jquery to grab the option value of whatever dropdown element is currently selected.

Right now I'm using this code but it's not working:

**JQUERY**

```
var a = $(".select1 option:selected");
```

However it's not bringing back "1", "2", "3", etc.

When I run console.log(a) I get the following:

[image: console log]

Not sure what's happening.

The idea is that I can use the variable a to load data like state.greens[a].price, state.greens[a].ingredients, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just give:

```
var a = $(".select1 option:selected").attr("value");
```

Or give this:

```
var a = $(".select1").val();
```

You need to get the value of the `<select>`.

Comment: ......thank you for this.  One other question:  when I console log the answer I get the correct index position but it still returns undefined.......do you know why this is?

Comment: Do you want to get the index position?

Comment: @JonathanBechtel To get the index position, you need to use `$("#select1").get(0).selectedIndex` or `$("#select1").[0].selectedIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = $(".select1").val(); // is the simple solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

HTML

```
<select class="select1" id="select1">
    <option value ="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value ="1">Option 2</option>
    <option value ="2">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Pure Javascript solution

```
document.getElementById("select1").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var a = document.getElementById("select1").value;

   alert(a);
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf5nv6xa/)

**Snippet**

```js
document.getElementById("select1").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var a = document.getElementById("select1").value;

   alert(a);
});
```

```html
<select class="select1" id="select1">
    <option value ="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value ="1">Option 2</option>
    <option valuae ="2">Option 3</option>
</select>
```